# How to remove tags in org-mode ical export?

Tags: emacs, export, elisp, icalendar, org-mode

Exporting an org-mode file to ical format, it seems that tags stay in events and todo titles. In agenda mode, i can remove them using *org-agenda-remove-tags* but i cannot find such an option for ical export. Is this feature implemented ?

Thank you for your advice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
```

to suppress the tags in exported files.

---

However, are you using the most up-to-date version fo Org-Mode?

I just tried doing what I understand your question to be and the tags don't seem to be included.

If I export the following headlines without the default settings:

```
* TODO Movie                                                :Movie:blah:
  Go see a movie
  <2011-09-17 Sat 13:00-14:00>
```

My .ics file has the following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:test
PRODID:-////Emacs with Org-mode//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:-0400
X-WR-CALDESC:nil
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID: TS-61193c39-f2e6-444c-9105-9499a2552bf5
DTSTART:20110917T130000
DTEND:20110917T140000
SUMMARY:TODO Movie
DESCRIPTION: Go see a movie\n<2011-09-17 Sat 13:00-14:00>
CATEGORIES:Movie,blah,test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I can see the tags listed as CATEGORIES, but not anywhere else.

The export only changes the UID if I add

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
```

to the file. Although an ASCII or HTML export will both suppress the tags when the option is added.